# Boost Bundled Properties: Do I need to initialize all properties for each edge?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, properties

I created a graph in boost and I am using bundled properties. I don't need each property for each edge, but I need all of them for some edges. My question is: can I not set some properties or do they all have to be set when creating the edge?

```
struct EdgeProperty 
{
    double weight;
    int index;
    int property_thats_only_used_sometimes;
    bool property_thats_only_used_sometimes2;
};
//would this be enough:
edge_descriptor edge = add_edge(u, v, graph).first;
graph[edge].weight = 5;
graph[edge].index = 1;
```

Comment: What's wrong with initializing all properties? If you don't know at initializing time which edge need all properties set, then yes you should initialize them all. Otherwise, juste initialize the properties needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to read the question:

> My question is: can I not set some properties

Not in the sense that they cannot be absent. The bundle type is the unit of instantiation.

> do they all have to be set when creating the edge?

Well no. This is C++. In your example, not "setting" them all will leave them at their indeterminate values. For non-primitive type, default-initialization would apply (say `std::string` would always get the default value of `""`).

To prevent indeterminate data you can simply provide initialization, either by adding a default constructor:

```
struct EdgeProperty {
    double weight;
    int index;
    int property_thats_only_used_sometimes;
    bool property_thats_only_used_sometimes2;

    EdgeProperty() 
      : weight(1.0), index(-1),
        property_thats_only_used_sometimes(0),
        property_thats_only_used_sometimes2(false)
    { }
};
```

or equivalently using NSMI:

```
struct EdgeProperty {
    double weight = 1.0;
    int index     = -1;
    int property_thats_only_used_sometimes   = 0; 
    bool property_thats_only_used_sometimes2 = false;
};
```

### Advanced Ideas

You might not know, but you can also pass properties directly to `add_edge`. If you want you can supply a suitable constructor to take the commonly set properties only:

```
struct EdgeProperty {
    double weight;
    int index;

    EdgeProperty(double w = 1.0, int i = -1) : weight(w), index(i)
    { }

    int property_thats_only_used_sometimes = 0;
    bool property_thats_only_used_sometimes2 = 0;
};
```

Now you can simply create the edge:

```
auto edge = add_edge(u, v, EdgeProperty(5, 1), graph).first;
```

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e763f831935b41d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

struct EdgeProperty {
    double weight;
    int index;

    EdgeProperty(double w = 1.0, int i = -1) : weight(w), index(i)
    { }

    int property_thats_only_used_sometimes = 0;
    bool property_thats_only_used_sometimes2 = 0;
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeProperty>;

int main() {
    Graph graph;
    auto u = add_vertex(graph);
    auto v = add_vertex(graph);

    //would this be enough:
    auto edge = add_edge(u, v, EdgeProperty(5, 1), graph).first;
}
```